# multiple inserts to database using mysqli

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

So i am updating my question as the coding has massively changed, thanks

So here is my premier_league.php page that is called upon when the league is selected ...

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" class="btn btn-medium btn-success"><br><br>
<?php

$leaguelist = '<option disabled>Please select team</option>';
if ($league_var == NULL) {
    $leaguelist .= '<option "disabled"><strong>Please Select a League Table</strong></h1>';
} else {
    $league_table = get_table($league_var);
foreach ($league_table as $rows) {    

        $leaguelist .= '<option>'.htmlspecialchars($rows['team']).'</option>';
    }
}
$needed_rows = ceil(count(get_table($league_var)) / 2);
for($i=1; $i <= $needed_rows; $i++){
?>
<select name="result[<?=$i?>][home]" id="" style="width:175px">
<?=$leaguelist?>
</select>

<input type="text" name="result[<?=$i?>][home-score]" class="edit_league_input" value="">
vs
<input type="text" name="result[<?=$i?>][away-score]" class="edit_league_input" name="" value="">
<select name="result[<?=$i?>][away]" id="" style="175px">
<?=$leaguelist?>
</select>
<input type="date" name="result[<?=$i?>][date]" style="width:150px;">
<input type="time" name="result[<?=$i?>][kickoff]" style="width:90px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="result[<?=$i?>][on-tv]" value="Yes" style="margin:-10px 5px 0px 5px;">on T.v
<input type="text" name="result[<?=$i?>][channel]" value="" placeholder="Channel..." style="width:100px;">
<select name="result[<?=$i?>][result]" id="" style="width:125px;">
<option value="">Match Choice...</option>
<option value="HT">Half Time</option>
<option value="FT">Full Time</option>
<option value="P">Postponed</option>
</select>
<br>
<?php
}
?>
```

So from that, you can see that the **one** row is now looped, and depending on how many teams are in the league, that will determine how many rows of fixtures are needed, in the Prem, this is 10.. so the page for the fixtures seems to be sorted, but if there seems to be something the matter, please bring it up and let me know..

Next was well, the original issue, about using **MySQLi** and adding the mulitple rows to a database. So again with help, the result ended up looking like this ...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($h); $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `fixtures` (`home`, `home-score`, `away-score`, `away`, `kickoff`, `on-tv`, `channel`, `league`, `result`, `date`)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $h[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $hs[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $as[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $a[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $time[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $tv[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $channel[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $league[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $result[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $date[$i]);
$success = $stmt->execute();

if ($success === false) {
    echo $stmt->errno . ": " . $stmt->error;
}
```

So now the main issue i guess, is how to fit this within a function, my functions sit on  **general.func.php** and i guess as there are 10 parameters, and there could be up to 12 rows that's up to 120 parameters pass through, so is there a shorter/cleaner way to pass that many parameters through a function?
With the variables being $x**[$i]** due to the loop, would i pass them through like that? so the function could read

```
add_function($h[$i], $hs[$i], $as[$i], $a[$i], $time[$i], $tv[$i], $channel[$i], $league[$i], $league[$i], $result[$i], $date[$i]) {...}
```

Or would i have to actually pass all the params through the function??

Comment: Why can't you loop through your data and run an insert statement for each row? You are correct: you should be preparing that query. You can do it, but you have to define a token for every single PHP variable you have in there. All 30 of them. Or you can bind 10 and run a loop three times.

Comment: its just a guess but would bind 10 then loop be the best way? if so, how would binding the 10 then looping through 3 times work? like i think i get the idea of it, it seems simple enough, binding the 10 variables to a row, then basically repeat on the next row and so on? but ill be honest and i just simply dont know how id do it, but i would like to know and understand so if i have to do it again or add more loops, so i can add more rows to the situation

Comment: You should only need one loop. Read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is never, ever a good reason to store variables as `$*1`...`$*n`. Use an array.

Second, here is how to prepare a statement:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($h); $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `fixtures` (`home`, `home-score`, `away-score`, `away`, `kickoff`, `on-tv`, `channel`, `league`, `result`, `date`)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $h[$i]);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $hs[$i]);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $as[$i]);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $a[$i]);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $time[$i]);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $tv[$i]);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $channel[$i]);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $league[$i]);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $result[$i]);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $date[$i]);
    $success = $stmt->execute();

    if ($success === false) {
        echo $stmt->errno . ": " . $stmt->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: the only reason why it is like that, because ive been looking for a way to do this for a day or so, and i was advise, clearly wrongly, that that way would be easier.. if that was the easy way..im not sure i want to know the hard way :-\..ok so bare with me a sec, i think i get how that works, the $x[$i] goes up each time it moves on to the next row, at the top the count($h)? does that basically count how many $h's there are so decides how many rows will go into the database? and if the $i is less than how many $h's there are, proceed and bind the params ... look like i understand ??

Comment: ok so i swapped out that code, and my success message came up, but the 3 rows were not in my database, could that be due to that some of the fields could be blank, so nothing is in them to insert? like channel, if the match was not on tv, there is no channel in the process so could make them not be entered to the database?

Comment: Wow. I love how someone cowardly -1'ed without so much as a comment. Anyway, what is your success message?

Comment: Add the last 6 lines of code that I just added and see what the error message is.

Comment: sorry boput the long delay, not been well... but i added the lines of code and nothing happened, nothing at all.. what would you suggest? cause if it were a success it would/should be in the data base, if not, an error should appear, so should i redo the function? .. basically its currently, if isset post['add'], check for errors bla bla, then if empty errors add_fixtures() .. thts the function, and then on my general.func.php page i have the function, with your added code, would you suggest keeping like that or changing it and the funciton?

Comment: omg ive been banned from asking anymore questions!! how exactly am i going to help anyone else if they ban me, in turn stopping me learning things, which stops me from helping people in the future? makes no sense at all!!

Comment: i guess ill have to ask here and hope someone actually see's it. so with the function, how would be the best way to pass parameters through? with them adding up, the more fixtures i have, they'll need to be passed through the function, so how would be best doing this...
add_fixture(then add individually all the $'s there would be?) or something like add_function($h[$i],$hs[$i]..) and so on?

Comment: the error message that came up was `mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement..2031: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement`

Comment: If you've been banned from asking questions it means that your questions were low quality and showed a lack of research. Add more information to all of your questions and try to get all of them answered. Then you should be unbanned.

Comment: Where/how are you defining h, hs, as, etc.? Put it in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (`home`, ...) VALUES (`$h1`, ...); ";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO tablename (`home`, ...) VALUES (`$h2`, ...); ";
```

Notice there are semicolons after each `INSERT` query. You can except the last one.

Alternative:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table (`home`, ...) VALUES( `$h1`, ... ), ( `$h2`, ... )";
```

Comment: im not sure from that how i would bind the parameters? cause say i have 4 rows, i would do 4 separate $sql lines like above, but have semicolons in the first 3.. in the values bracket.. would i use '?' or '$h1'? then when it comes to $result->bind_param(); how would i solve this?

Comment: In first bracket use column name (eg. home) and in the second bracket use your variables (eg. $h1).

Comment: Plus your alternative, thats just the same thing as the '$sql = ...'  that i actually put :S

Comment: firstly, i want to be able to prepare and bind_param the query... but when i ran the query from above, with $result = $db->query($sql); and **NOT** $result = $db->prepare($sql),  .. well it just doesnt enter the database

Comment: Don't post long code in comments. Edit it into your question.

Comment: As a disclaimer, I didn't -1 your answer.